# For which functions $\phi$ series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Function $\phi$ is continuous on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. For which functions $\phi$ series converges
$$\phi \in C([-\pi,\pi])$$
$$1)\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\phi(t)}{\cos t + \ln n}dt,$$
$$2)\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\phi(t)}{\sin t + \ln n}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

You should try to understand the behaviour of the $n$-th term of the sequence as $n$ tends to infinity. First of all, since $n \geq 3$ all the denominators are positive. This implies all terms of the sequence are finite since $\phi$ is a continuous function on a compact interval and hence has a maximum and a minimum.

Notice that for large $n$ we have $\log n$ is the dominant part of the denominator, since $\cos t \in [-1, 1]$ for every $t$. Thus, for the series above to converge we should have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=3}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\phi(t)}{\log n}dt = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{\log n} \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \phi(t) dt
\end{equation}
is convergent. Recall that $\sum_{n \geq 3} \frac{1}{\log n}$ is divergent. Thus, a necessary condition is that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi(t) \, \text{d}t = 0$. Try to formalize this.